# How can I filter packets from a port monitor?

Tags: monitoring, voip, wireshark

I have some data going from Point A to Point B.  I have a SPAN monitor set up to a monitoring device C.

To recreate some real world scenarios, I want to filter out all traffic which is a certain type (H.323 VoIP Signaling Packets) so that C sees a subset of the information that is flowing from A to B.

What would the easiest way to do this be?  I assume I would need a computer with 2 NIC cards and some software to examine each packet and chuck out the H.323 VoIP packets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with almost any hardware and software you want. You do need a PC with 2 NIC cards. Personally, I'd use Linux's software bridging and [`ebtables`](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/) to enforce the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use a capture filter in wireshark...